# What to check in cross-validation - MAE or MSE?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, error

When using cross-validation for model selection, should one look at MSE or MAE. I know that MSE and MAE are related but which is the more appropriate measure?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48267/mean-absolute-error-or-root-mean-squared-error <- this might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for re-asking this question. The answer to this question is available in this thread

[Mean absolute error OR root mean squared error?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48267/mean-absolute-error-or-root-mean-squared-error)