# How to modify RMSE loss function to adopt for integer valued predictions, using a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, mse

Context: Prediction of dependent variables like Age, Siblings, Children, etc (which are not categorical, but bounded, and integer-valued) from a dataset using Neural Network. I'm experimenting with a simple network, and plan to train it using Gradient Descent for starters.

While RMSE is a natural choice for minimization, the predictions currently are float values. I could probably round the predictions (or ceil/floor them) and calculate the loss (again using RMSE), but is that a correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the number of children. If for a given instance, one or two children are equally probable outcomes, then the expectation prediction is 1.5 children. This is [what the (R)MSE will pull you towards](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210857/1352).

If you want an unbiased prediction of a count (or binary) variable, you will usually get a non-integer value.

Whether this is a problem for you depends on what you plan on doing with your prediction. For instance, you may actually want a quantile prediction, which would indeed be integer.