# Cross Validation - different types of error

Tags: cross-validation

When doing LOOCV, is there a difference between mean absolute error, and root mean square error? As you're only testing on a single data point, I think they should be the same?

Comment: It might make sense to post your two questions separately. On the first paragraph, [this may be helpful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210857/1352) - using different loss functions will lead your model to target different conditional functionals (the median for MAE, the mean for MSE).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Okay - I'll create a separate question for the second part.

Comment: @StephanKolassa But for the first part, I get they're different generally, but from a calculation perspective aren't they identical when doing leave one out cross validation?

Comment: I have posted an answer which hopefully addresses your comment. Please consider deleting the second paragraph of your question (and reposting it separately).

Answer (score 1):

> When doing LOOCV, is there a difference between mean absolute error, and root mean square error? As you're only testing on a single data point, I think they should be the same?

No, they aren't. After all, you are not testing on a *single* data point, but on *each separate* data point, and then aggregating the average or squared errors by averaging.

As an example, assume your data consists of just five points $\{0,0,0,1,4\}$, and your model has no predictors at all, so you are just looking for a single number $y$ that "best" describes your data - and you are trying to find this number via LOOCV.

[Per this explanation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210857/1352), your LOOCV MAE will be minimized by the *median*, which is $0$ - but your LOOCV MSE will be minimized by the *mean*, which is $1$:

[image: MAE vs MSE]

R code:

```
obs <- c(0,0,0,1,4)
y <- seq(min(obs),max(obs),by=.1)
MAEs <- sapply(y,function(x)mean(abs(x-obs)))
MSEs <- sapply(y,function(x)mean((x-obs)^2))

par(mfrow=c(1,2),las=1)
plot(y,MAEs,type="l",ylab="",main="MAE")
abline(v=y[which.min(MAEs)],col="red",lwd=2)
plot(y,MSEs,type="l",ylab="",main="MSE")
abline(v=y[which.min(MSEs)],col="red",lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It makes sense, but I'm still confused where the error in my logic is.

For RMSE, I'm calculating np.sqrt(np.sum((ytest-ypred)**2)). However, in LOOCV this is a single element, and so you just have sqrt((ytest-ypred)**2) = abs(ytest-ypred), which is the same value you'd get using an absolute error. I get that you would then average each of these errors over the different points, but don't the MAE and RMSE already give the same value before you get to averaging over the different points?

If that's not clear.I can try and write something clearer.

Comment: Ah. But then you are not calculating the SE, but indeed the AE per observation, and in aggregating end up with the MAE in both cases. If you want to use the (R)MSE, then you need to aggregate the squares, not take the square root per instance.

Comment: This may be better asked in another new question, but I'm then confused about how you would perform say k-fold cross validation when $k$ is less than the number of samples.
If you have a testing set consisting of multiple values, isn't it just these that you would sum. Or would you sum across all these values, and then sum over every testing set, and then square root/ take an absolute value?

Comment: Hm. I think that would indeed make for a separate question, and ideally one with a couple of formulas that note precisely what you are thinking about - as we saw, "RMSE" can mean different things to different people.